# Plotly-Dash scrollZoom = False for mobile not working as on desktop

Tags: python, mobile, plotly-dash

Same question asked on the [plotly community forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/scrollzoom-false-for-mobile-or-non-changing-heatmap-radius-on-zoom/59681).

I am creating a dash app which utilizes `plotly-dash` `density_mapbox` and I would like to disable the ability for the user to zoom, as it effects the radius of the heatmap and misrepresents this particular dataset, in my opinion.

Setting `scrollZoom = False` in the `config` of `dcc.Graph` works as intended on desktop--the user can't zoom but can pan and move around, and interact with the graph. However, on mobile devices `scrollZoom = False` doesn't appear to do anything--the user can still zoom in and out.

`staticPlot = True` was a recommended solution, but that will not work because I'd like for the datapoints to be viewable on hover. Making the graph static removes all interaction.

Below is the sample code with sample dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

rgba = 'rgba(248, 246, 243, 1)'

date = [1,1,2,2]
lat = [30, 31, 30, 31]
longs = [-90, -93, -90, -93]
loc = ['Point A', 'Point B', 'Point A', 'Point B']
count = [300, 450, 310, 600]
lwr = 0
upr = 600

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(date, lat,longs,loc,count), columns=['Date','lat','long','Location','count'])

# Initialize the app server, starting info, and rgba of background
app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags = [{'name': 'viewport',
                             'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
                            }]
                   )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# App layout (REMEMBER, BOOTSTRAP LAYOUT HAS 12 COLUMNS)
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    
        # Row 1
        dbc.Row([
        
        # Row 1, Column 1 -- The Date Select Slider
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Slider(id='select_date',
                       min=1, 
                       max=2, 
                       value=1,
                           marks={
                               1: 'Date 1',
                               2: 'Date 2'
                           },
                       included=False
                      )
        ],
            width={'size': 12, 'offset': 0},
            style={'height': '10vh', 'backgroundColor': rgba},
            align='center'
        ),
            
    ], no_gutters=True, align='center', justify='center'),
    
        # Row 2
        dbc.Row([
        
        # Row 2, Column 1 -- The Migration Map
        dbc.Col([       
            dcc.Graph(id='migration_map',
                      figure={},
                      config={'displayModeBar': False
                              ,'scrollZoom': False # This gets rid of the ability to zoom, BUT ONLY ON DESKTOP
                             }, 
                      responsive=True,
                      style={'height': '80vh', 'top': '50%', 'left': '50%', 'backgroundColor': rgba}
                     ),
        ],
            width={'size': 12, 'offset': 0},
            style={'height': '90vh', 'backgroundColor': rgba}
        ),
        
    ], no_gutters=True, align='center', justify='center'),
    
], fluid=True, style={'backgroundColor': rgba})

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect the Plotly graphs with Dash Components
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='migration_map', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='select_date', component_property='value')
)

def update_graph(selected_date):
    
    ###############################################
    ##### Start forming the desired DataFrame #####
    ###############################################
    
    dff = df.copy()
    
    dff = dff[(dff['Date'] == selected_date)]

    # Create the figure
    fig = px.density_mapbox(dff
                            ,lat='lat'
                            ,lon='long'
                            ,z='count'
                            ,hover_name='Location'
                            ,center=dict(lat=39, lon=-91)
                            ,zoom=3.475
                            ,mapbox_style='carto-positron'
                            ,opacity = 0.4
                            ,radius = 25
                            ,range_color = [lwr, upr]
                            ,color_continuous_scale=['rgb(0,0,0)',
                                                     'rgb(19,48,239)',
                                                     'rgb(115,249,253)',
                                                     'rgb(114,245,77)',
                                                     'rgb(254,251,84)',
                                                     'rgb(235,70,38)']
    #                             ,color_continuous_scale='inferno'
                           )


    return fig


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this later on, follow the issue and its resolution [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6087).